# App is having trouble with Google Play Services. If it persists, please contact the developer for assistance

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am trying to integrate the `Google Drive API` for Android with my Android application.

My senior created a project on the Google Developer console using the app package name and the `SHA1` from my machine and generated the `OAuth 2.0` client ID (I have no access to the account).

On the click of a button, I have to enable the user to access the files on Drive so as to upload them to the server.

I call the following code `onClick()`:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(Activity.this)
    .addApi(Drive.API)
    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(Activity.this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(Activity.this)
    .build();

mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

This calls the `onConnectionFailed()` callback:

```
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed");
    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed - Trying again");
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RESOLVE_CONNECTION_REQUEST_CODE);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            // Unable to resolve, message user appropriately
        }
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed, Code : " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(connectionResult.getErrorCode(), this, 0).show();
    }
}
```

The connection fails and it tries again. On retrying, it calls the `onActivityResult()` and tries to connect again:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {
    if (requestCode == Constants.RESOLVE_CONNECTION_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Code match");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}
```

This time again the connection attempt fails, with error code 8 and gives the message "App is having trouble with Google Play Services. If the problem persists, please contact the developer for assistance."

I read this too:
[<Your App> is having trouble with Google Play services - When using GoogleApiClient, it always trigger onConnectionFailed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37476432/your-app-is-having-trouble-with-google-play-services-when-using-googleapicli), but did not help.

I tried looking it up on Google but nothing has helped yet. Any assistance will be great!

Answer (score 0):

Try not to instatiate `mGoogleApiClient` in your click `onClick()` function. If you check this [android-demo](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/BaseDemoActivity.java) and this [drive quickstart](https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/quickstart/MainActivity.java), the mGoogleApiClient is instantiated in the `onResume()` lifecycyle:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();
if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
// Create the API client and bind it to an instance variable.
// We use this instance as the callback for connection and connection
// failures.
// Since no account name is passed, the user is prompted to choose.
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
.addApi(Drive.API)
.addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
.addConnectionCallbacks(this)
.addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
.build();
}
// Connect the client. Once connected, the camera is launched.
mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

Check the official [Android Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started) for more info.

Comment: Yes. I have checked that. But that would cause the Account selection dialog to pop up `onResume()`. I do not want that. I want that dialog to be shown only in case the user wants to access files from Google Drive.